# Recursion function question again

Tags: recursion

http://vvcap.net/db/3RxO1KX2d4LxgD714Tyh.htp

mult(x,y)= mult(x-1,y)+4
mult(0,4)=0

mult(1,4)=mult(0,4)+4
mult(2,4)=mult(1,4)+4
mult(3,4)=mult(2,4)+4

I'm not sure whether this is correct, but i think it does calculate the four time tables ? since it's just adding four to the previous one

Comment: What means "again" in the title? If you've posted something related previously, a link would be a good idea.

Comment: I think this is the 3rd question in the last few hours. Anyway, the link does not work for me.

Comment: You aren't limited to the amount of questions you can ask. I'll use the resources available to me, it's optional whether you want to help or not.

Comment: It's optional whether you want to make it easier for others to help, by including relevant links, learning how to do formatting on this site, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I will show a method using Python code.  This works for integer $m, n \ge 0$.

```
 def mult(m, n):
        if(n == 0):
             return 0
        return mult(m, n - 1) + m
```

Comment: At least i now know this is relevant :P we're yet to do Python, but hopefully we will since it's obviously useful for the Maths we're being taught! ty

Comment: It's pretty easy to figure out what the Python is saying, even if you have never programmed in it before.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting problem, because it requires 2 inputs. I believe the following function work for any m, or n.

mult(m,n = 0), mult(m,n) = mult(m,n-1) + m